# How to allow duplicate values from two different list into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two different list which is a result I got after scraping,
I have this two dataset below

```
names = [ 'Forbes', 'Forbes', 'Forbes', 'Forbes', 'Forbes', 'Forbes', 'MobilePunch', 'MobilePunch', 
         'MobilePunch','MobilePunch', 'MobilePunch', 'MobilePunch','ARISE', 'ARISEtv', 
         'ARISEtv','ARISEtv','ARISEtv']



address = ['http://on.forbes.com/6010G4rPO',
 'https://www.forbes.com/sites/danielcassady/2020/10/15/positive-test-rate-dropping-in-nyc-hotspots-mayor-says/?utm_campaign=forbes&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_term=Gordie/#676f7264696',
 'https://www.forbes.com/sites/johnkoetsier/2020/10/15/yes-twitter-is-down-no-its-not-just-you/?utm_campaign=forbes&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_term=Valerie/#76616c657269',
 'http://on.forbes.com/6012G4Juo', 'http://on.forbes.com/6018G4yCM', 'http://on.forbes.com/6018G48zs',
 'https://punchng.com/ighalo-ready-to-grab-man-united-chance/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602804559',
 'https://punchng.com/fayose-commiserates-with-makinde-over-mums-death/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602803764',
 'https://punchng.com/reversing-missed-opportunities-in-agoa/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602796809',
 'https://punchng.com/champions-league-psgs-icardi-out-of-match-against-manchester-utd/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602795929',
 'https://punchng.com/breaking-asuu-strike-fg-agrees-to-pay-n30bn-earned-allowance/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602795928',
 'https://punchng.com/endsars-kwara-gov-deputy-lead-protesters-to-police-headquarters/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602793339',
 'https://www.arise.tv/hogwash-nonsense-former-nigerian-governor-duke-carpets-move-to-ban-protests-in-abuja/',
 'https://www.arise.tv/endsars-nigerian-army-warns-subversive-elements-against-undemocratic-acts/',
 'https://www.arise.tv/nigerias-army-chief-has-failed-former-governor-duke-says/',
 'https://www.arise.tv/continued-stay-of-service-chiefs-a-huge-problem-for-nigeria-says-ahmed-buhari/',
 'https://www.arise.tv/tesla-reduces-price-of-model-s-sedan/']
```

**I now want to convert the two list into dictionary where the name list is the key and the address the value**

when i run this code below

```
celebrity_and_gossip_rss_dict = dict(zip(names, address))
print( celebrity_and_gossip_rss_dict)
```

I have the result below

```
{'TechCabal': 'https://twitter.com/TechCabal/status/1316759740437991424', 'cnnbrk': 'https://cnn.it/3kfLSAR', 'Forbes': 'http://on.forbes.com/6018G48zs', 'vanguardngrnews': 'https://www.vanguardngr.com/2020/10/troops-impound-stolen-products-destroy-illegal-refining-sites-in-south-south/', 'MobilePunch': 'https://punchng.com/endsars-kwara-gov-deputy-lead-protesters-to-police-headquarters/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602793339', 'ARISEtv': 'https://www.arise.tv/tesla-reduces-price-of-model-s-sedan/'}
```

this is not the result i'm expecting as this is only picking the first key and neglects others, i want all the other keys i have in the the name list to appear in the dictionary with their different values

Comment: keys in a dictionary must be unique... what do you expect to happen?

Comment: The behavior you describe is not one of the dictionary. You could see some success in just using the zip directly (a list of lists) or generating a dictionary, whose values are lists of addresses.

Comment: I want to have all the keys with their different values, is their a way to allow that

Comment: no. you could have a dict like `{name1: [url1, url2], name2: [url3, url3]}`.

Comment: just avoiding that for some reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to allow duplicate keys in a dictionary. what is`dct[key]` supposed to return?

what you could do is use a list as values of the dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

names = ...
address = ...

dct = defaultdict(list)

for name, addr in zip(names, address):
    dct[name].append(addr)

print(dct)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
#  'Forbes': 
#    ['http://on.forbes.com/6010G4rPO', 'https://www.forbes.com/sites/danielcassady/2020/10/15/positive-test-rate-dropping-in-nyc-hotspots-mayor-says/?utm_campaign=forbes&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_term=Gordie/#676f7264696', 'https://www.forbes.com/sites/johnkoetsier/2020/10/15/yes-twitter-is-down-no-its-not-just-you/?utm_campaign=forbes&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_term=Valerie/#76616c657269', 'http://on.forbes.com/6012G4Juo', 'http://on.forbes.com/6018G4yCM', 'http://on.forbes.com/6018G48zs'],
# 'MobilePunch': 
#   ['https://punchng.com/ighalo-ready-to-grab-man-united-chance/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602804559', 'https://punchng.com/fayose-commiserates-with-makinde-over-mums-death/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602803764', 'https://punchng.com/reversing-missed-opportunities-in-agoa/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602796809', 'https://punchng.com/champions-league-psgs-icardi-out-of-match-against-manchester-utd/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602795929', 'https://punchng.com/breaking-asuu-strike-fg-agrees-to-pay-n30bn-earned-allowance/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602795928', 'https://punchng.com/endsars-kwara-gov-deputy-lead-protesters-to-police-headquarters/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=Social&utm_source=Twitter#Echobox=1602793339'], 
# 'ARISE': 
#   ['https://www.arise.tv/hogwash-nonsense-former-nigerian-governor-duke-carpets-move-to-ban-protests-in-abuja/'], 
# 'ARISEtv': 
#   ['https://www.arise.tv/endsars-nigerian-army-warns-subversive-elements-against-undemocratic-acts/', 'https://www.arise.tv/nigerias-army-chief-has-failed-former-governor-duke-says/', 'https://www.arise.tv/continued-stay-of-service-chiefs-a-huge-problem-for-nigeria-says-ahmed-buhari/', 'https://www.arise.tv/tesla-reduces-price-of-model-s-sedan/']})
```

Comment: thank you, i have been avoiding this approach, i think i will have to twist them around, since the values are different